# UITextField placeholder issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app you can select one of the two rows in the first section (section 0). When you select one the rows the row in the section 2 (section 1) reloads. When you change now the selection several times, the placeholder doesn't disappears. (when you change the selection for 1 or 2 times the placeholder disappears). What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Here's how I create the UITextField in the cell:

```
if (!self.selectedType) {
            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ", self.LessonToDisplay];
            int where = (string.length*5)+35;

            self.textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(where, 10, 150, 25)];
            self.textField.tag = 42;
            self.textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:16];
            self.textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            if([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
                self.textField.placeholder = @"Beschreibung";
            }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ", self.LessonToDisplay];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            } else {
                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Prüfung", self.LessonToDisplay];
            int where = (string.length*5.8)+57;
            self.textField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(where, 10, 150, 25)];
            self.textField2.tag = 43;
            self.textField2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:16];
            self.textField2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                if([self.textField2.text isEqualToString:@""]){
                    self.textField2.placeholder = @"Beschreibung";
                }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.textField2];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Prüfung ", self.LessonToDisplay];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
```

Comment: Cells get reused. You are probable adding the text field over and over as the cell gets reused. Be sure you only add the text field once per cell.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Don't add it if it's already there. Simply code logic.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your help, it is working now with that what Corey suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of @rmaddy's comment, the cells are reused. So, adding a subview to a cells content view will just stack from the previous use. You could just remove all subviews from the cells contentView before adding additional subviews:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```